# Including graphics in latex classfile

Tags: latex, miktex

I have some class files in latex with a company logo on the titlepage. I have now stored all templates for this company in one folder and added this path to MiKTeX . I have placed the logo in a child folder of the templates named "graphics". In the class files I then import the logo with \includegraphics{./graphics/logo}. This gives a file not found error.

Is there a way to have the logo at one place? Or do I need to copy the logo to the same place as I have the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your templates follow the required texmf structure. I put figures inside the `tex/latex/...` folder. I'm not sure if they have to go there, but they are always found if I put them there.
2. There is no need to give the path. Just use `\includegraphics{logo}`. If logo is not in the local directory, MikTeX will search the path to find it (and will automatically look in sub-directories).
3. Also, make sure you have refreshed the filename database after you added the logo file.

Comment: Thank you, that did work! The thing was that I had added the logo afther I had Refreshed FNDB...